# Place Search box с координатами

Tags: android, kotlin

Как правильно добиться того, чтобы после ввода координат, он ставил метку, а не говорил что "ничего не найдено" как приведено на картинке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мои догадки заключаются в том, чтобы отлавливать данный статус ошибки, следующим образом:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        switch(requestCode){
            case PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE:
                switch(resultCode){
                    case RESULT_OK:
                         ...
                         break;
                    case RESULT_ERROR:
                         if (!PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data).isSuccess()) {
                              markerPlace = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data).getLatLng()).icon(vectorToBitmap(R.drawable.ic_place_black_24dp, ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimaryDark))));
                              autocompleteFragment.setText(PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data).getLatLng() + "");
                         } //мой способ ловли
                         break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Но к сожалению он игнорит данный способ...

Comment: А зачем игнорит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению, я ничего не нашел официального. Да и вообще перешел на `Yandex MapKit v3`

---

**Забываем про PlaceAutocomplete. Идем по харду.**

---

Начнем с дизайна, запариваясь:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/search_place_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:background="@color/colorNull">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_place_et"
            style="@style/CustomEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.8"
            android:background="@color/colorNull"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:digits="0123456789.,-"
            android:hint="@string/place_search_hint"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            tools:ignore="Autofill" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/clear_search_iv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_clear_grey_24dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Цвета:

```
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</color>
<color name="colorNull">#fafafa</color>
<color name="colorClearImage">#717171</color> // цвет для 'Х' (картинка)
```

Стиль:

```
<style name="CustomEditText">
    <item name="android:theme">@style/EditTextAppTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="EditTextAppTheme">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

**Итог:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
private fun searchPlace() {
        search_place_et.setOnTouchListener { _, _ ->
            searchPlaceCursorOn()
            false
        }
        search_place_et.setOnEditorActionListener(TextView.OnEditorActionListener { _, id, _ ->
            if (id == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                searchPlaceCursorOff()

                if (search_place_et.text.matches(latLngPattern.toRegex())) {
                    val arrayLatLng = search_place_et.text.split(",".toRegex())
                    val searchPlaceLatitude = arrayLatLng[0].toDouble()
                    val searchPlaceLongitude = arrayLatLng[1].toDouble()
                    drawMarkerSearchPlace(searchPlaceLatitude, searchPlaceLongitude)
                } else {
                    val requestStart = getString(R.string.search_place_request_start) // По запросу
                    val requestEnd = getString(R.string.search_place_request_end) // ничего не найдено
                    toast("$requestStart '${search_place_et.text}' $requestEnd") // anko
                }
                return@OnEditorActionListener true
            }
            true
        })
        search_place_et.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {}

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                when {
                    s.isNotEmpty() -> {
                        clear_search_iv.animate().alpha(1.0f).setListener(
                            object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
                                    clear_search_iv.visibility = VISIBLE
                                    clear_search_iv.setOnClickListener {
                                        search_place_et.setText("")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        )
                    }
                    s.isEmpty() -> {
                        clear_search_iv.animate().alpha(0.0f).setListener(
                            object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
                                    clear_search_iv.visibility = INVISIBLE
                                }
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

---

### [Полный код на GitHub](https://github.com/iFr0z/SearchPlaceBox)